# Best image hosting solution

Tags: image, hosting, amazon-s3

Due to the heavy load and disk occupation, I want to move all of my website images to a separate dedicated server or Amazon S3. But I doubt there is not control on data if we move to S3 like downloading all the data or moving to another provider from S3.

Please give me your suggestion as to which is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no data lock in with Amazon S3 and you have complete control over your files. You are free to move your data off S3 at any time.

S3 could easily cope with your 'heavy' load and you can make use of Amazon's [Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) CDN to speed up delivery in edge locations.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading the following article, written by one of the founders of Stack Overflow. It describes his experience and reasoning for using Amazon's S3 service for image hosting.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/using-amazon-s3-as-an-image-hosting-service.html